# JRE EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION any solution for this

Tags: java

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d81bcd7, pid=5760, tid=6008
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b22 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x5bcd7]
```

When I run the program in `debug` mode, then the above issue appears otherwise, if I `run` mode the program runs well
environment : Eclipse IDE, java 1.6

Comment: I'm not sure anyone on SO can help with hard JVM crashes - this an issue for Oracle support if anything. Try reinstalling the JDK in case something got corrupted.

Comment: I re-insalled the JDK, but same issue .. please guide on how this can be solved

Comment: Do you have a goat handy? Or a virgin? We can't really even begin to this without you running a debug build of the JRE that would give us some sort of stack trace or at least a source code location of the crash. Or without analysing the heap dump. And I'm not saying that even if you provided these someone would bother.